# Transaction when saving many object in Grails service

Tags: grails, transactions, rollback

I am having a problem with transaction in Grails. I want to save a list of object to DB by a checking condition at each object. All these process I want to put to one transaction, it means if the k-th object does not satisfied the checking condition, all previous objects (from the first object to the (k-1)th one) will be rolled back from DB. Here is my example:

```
static transactional = true

public void saveManyPeople() {
    // ...
    List<People> peoples = new ArraysList();
    for(i = 0, i < n, i++) {
         People newPeople = createPeopleFromRawData(); // return a people object in memory
         if(<checking-condition>) {
              newPeople.save(flush : false)  
         } else {
               throw new MyCustomizedException()  // MyCustomizedException has extended from RuntimException
         }
    }
    // ...
}
```

As you may see, I set transactional variable to true and I've tried to use flush : true and flush : false, but it didn't work as I want. I've read this article [Rolling back a transaction in a Grails Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979786/rolling-back-a-transaction-in-a-grails-service)
And the author recommended that the service method should throw a RuntimeException then the process will be rollbacked. But if I want to throw another exception, so what I have to do?
Could you please give me some suggestions on this problem?
Thank you so much!

Comment: How does it work then? Where do you call it from, can it be that it's called from another service?

Comment: Hi Victor, the function saveManyPeople() is in my service class, and this function will be called from controller, not from another service class. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can throw any exception that extends from RuntimeException to rollback the transaction. Or you can use [Programmatic Transactions](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#5.6%20Programmatic%20Transactions), using withTransation, to have more control over the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Could you verify that saveManyPeople() is within a Service and not a Controller?

The `static transactional = true` isn't respected in a Controller. I am suspecting that this is the issue.

If you need to have transactional support with the controller, you could always use DomainClass.withTransaction. [Reference Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withTransaction.html)
Example:

```
Account.withTransaction { status ->
    def source = Account.get(params.from)
    def dest = Account.get(params.to)
    def amount = params.amount.toInteger()
    if(source.active) {
        source.balance -= amount
        if(dest.active) {
            dest.amount += amount
        }
        else {
            status.setRollbackOnly()
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hi Derek, the function saveManyPeople() and the transactional variable I define in my service class. Your example looks like a snippet at controller class, doesn't it? AFAIK, we can handle transaction in Grails service automatically by set transactional = true, and nothing more to do. But in my case, it's very strange when some previous objects had been stored to DB cannot be rolled back though I threw a RuntimeException (MyCustomizedException extends from it). Thanks!

Comment: As a test, what happens when you set transactional=false and manage your own programmatic transactions (Domain.withTransaction & setRollbackOnly())? This might narrow down the problem area. If it exhibits the same behavior then we may need to start looking at your database/jdbc/transactionManager settings.