# How to rollback in case of failure in grails in below case

Tags: java, grails

Following is the class which saves the Book List, Student List & to the mapping for Student & Book based on some constraints.

```
class SaveMyDataService {
     @ Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    def saveBooks(List < Book > bookList) {

        /*
        some operation on bookList and then saving each Book Object individually
         */

    }
     @ Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    def saveStudent(List < Student > studentList) {

        /*
        some operation on studentList and then saving each Student Object individually
         */

    }

     @ Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    def saveStudentBookMapping() {

        List < Book > bookList = Book.getAll();
        List < Student > studentList = Studnet.getAll();

        for (int i = 0; i < studnetList.size(); i++) {
            StudentBookMapping obj = new StudentBookMapping();
            /*
            after some operation we map the Book & Student and save the StudentBookMapping Object
             */
            obj.save();
        }

    }

}
```

This service class invokes the methods of SaveMyDataService & other services to get the data and after that it do some evaluation 
where there might be possibility of getting exception in such a case I'm expecting to rollback of all the data i.e. Books, Students & their mapping but its not working out.

```
class FetchAllNewBooksAndStudent{

    def saveMyDataService;
    def xmlParsingSerivice;
    def evaluationService;

    getStudentAndBooksData()
    {
        try{
        /*
            Some IO operations to get the Student & Book List from XML
        */
        List<Student> studList = xmlParsing.getStudList();
        List<Book> bookList = xmlParsing.getBookList();

        // here we call the save book service
        saveMyDataService.saveBooks(bookList);

        // here we call the save Student service
        saveMyDataService.saveStudent(studList);


        // here we call the mapping service to map the Student & Books
        saveMyDataService.saveStudentBookMapping();

        /*
            after this I do some Evaluation operation but here might be chances of getting exception in such a case I want to rollback all the above entries made like books, student & their mapping but its not working out 
        */

        evaluationService.evaluate();


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            log.error e.getMessage();
        }

    }
}
```

This job runs after each 4 hrs to check the new data of Student/Books/StudentBookMapping and calls the getStudentAndBooksData service of fetchAllNewBooksAndStudent class

```
class RegularBookStudentCheckJob{

    def fetchAllNewBooksAndStudent;

    static triggers = {
        simple repeatInterval: Long.parseLong(ConfigHolder.config.REGULAR_BOOK_STUDENT_CHECK_JOB_REPEAT_INTERVAL), // here value is 4hrs
        startDelay : 60000
    }


    def execute(){

        if(String.valueOf(ConfigHolder.config.RUN_BOOK_STUDENT_CHECK_JOB).equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
        {
            fetchAllNewBooksAndStudent.getStudentAndBooksData();
        }

    }


}
```

Here my problem is in case of failure of Evaluation I'm expecting complete rollback of all data but its not working out can you please let me know where I'm making mistake.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: To roll back transactions you need to throw a run time exception  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979786/rolling-back-a-transaction-in-a-grails-service

Answer (score 0):

While calling save() method pass argument of failOnError:true i.e; save(failOnError:true)

Comment: No there is no error while saving, Exception can occure while `evaluation()` and there is no `save()` called for anything